# Does java compiler needs access to Interface in the signature of the methods we are using?

Tags: java

Let's say I have four modules, in a multi model set up project.

Instead of copying the gradle build, for convenience these are the dependencies among themselves, all with **implementation** scope.

```
user module -> account utility module
            -> account entity module
            
account utility module -> account interface module
account entity module -> account interface module
account interface module -> no dependency
```

Each module contains a single class, listing below:

**User.java**

```
import com.example.account.AccountEntity;
import com.example.util.AccountUtility;

public class User {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccountEntity accountEntity = new AccountEntity();
        AccountUtility.checkAccount(accountEntity);
    }
}
```

**AccountUtility.java**

```
package com.accountutility;


import com.accountinterface.AccountInterface;

public class AccountUtility {
    public static void checkAccount(AccountInterface account) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

**AccountInterface.java**

```
package com.accountinterface;

public interface AccountInterface {
}
```

**AccountEntity.java**

```
package com.accountentity;

import com.accountinterface.AccountInterface;

public class AccountEntity implements AccountInterface {
}
```

Gradle is complaining that user module  cannot access the account interface module.
My question is why the java compiler needs to access the **AccountInterface** bytecode ?

Is it because the compiler needs to make sure that the class we are using is indeed an implementation of the interface ?

If so why is no import for the interface needed ?

Also can this be cumbersome to handle when using java module system ?

EDIT:
So these are different modules or projects so you can think of it as the **AccountUtility** bytecode is already compiled and mentioned in the **classpath** when we try to compile **User.java**, the question is why the compiler still needs access to the bytecode of AccountInterface at compile time.

Comment: because of the call to `AccountUtility.checkAccount`  ?!?; eventual  How else would the compiler know number and type of parameter; eventual exceptions; and return type (but maybe I did not correctly understand the question...)

Comment: ahh spotted the typo, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why the java compiler needs to access the AccountUtility ?

Because.. you're using it. Right here: User.java, line 7:

> `AccountUtility.checkAccount(accountEntity);`

If it worked the way you apparently think it does, that `javac` does not need to know, then you could write `Doobedeedoodah.whatever()` and that should compile. If your cat then walked across your keyboard, that should also compile. Hey, if it isn't there at runtime, crash then, right?

Java does not work like that.

> If so why is no import for the interface needed ?

You appear to be suffering from a second misunderstanding. `import` is not like `import` in languages like javascript or python. **Import does absolutely nothing whatsoever**: It's a hint to the compiler, it does not result in *any* bytecode at all. It is simply an alias, nothing more. `import com.foo.Bar;` means: "Whenever in this code, "Bar" appears anyplace a type is required, act as if the source code read "com.foo.Bar" instead".

It does not mean 'run this code'. This knife cuts both ways: `import`ing something doesn't mean that class will be initialized. And *not* importing a thing doesn't mean that you can't use what you didn't import. Importing and class accessibility / initialization are **unrelated**.

You don't need to import it here because your code does not mention `AccountInterface` anywhere inside it. That doesn't mean `AccountInterface` is or isn't required at runtime or when compiling this code; that would depend on what the code does.

EDIT:

From a comment by OP:

> sorry indeed, I was referring to the AccountInterface bytecode, of course we need the AccountUtility :), can you re formulate your answer if you have time, I would appreciate it.

The parameter of the `checkAccount` method is `AccountInterface`. This means it's required for the *user* module to make sense of this method. Yes, the method itself is accessible and is in the right module, but it is using a type in its *signature* (the combination of its return type, the parameter types, and what it throws - signatures are *not* about the code in the method itself), and anything used in a signature that you want to call needs to also be visible, accessible, and known, or you can't compile code that tries to call it. Even if you are passing a parameter that is of a type that *is* accessible to your code and happens to be a subtype of the thing that is needed.

Further attempts to ask 'but why' on that pretty much boil down to 'cuz spec said so' / 'cuz spec writer wanted it to be so', and start veering out of range of what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: sorry indeed, I was referring to the AccountInterface bytecode, of course we need the AccountUtility :), can you re formulate your answer if you have time, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about true Java modules, with `module-info.java` files, or some construct of a build tool like Maven?

If the former, both your account utility and account entity modules should express their dependencies on the account interface module with `requires transitive`, not simply `requires`. Then things that depend on the utility and entity modules would automatically get the dependency on the interface module (the interface module would be automatically "readable").

Even if these are not real Java modules, you should ensure that dependencies are listed in the correct scope. In Gradle, the utility and entity modules would list the interface module in their "api" configurations, rather than "implementation", because types from that dependency are part of their own public API. I assume there are parallels to this concept in Maven and other tools. By placing them in the right configuration, the tool can create appropriate classpaths for compile- and run-time.

Comment: Hi eickson, I am testing this locally, for the compile dependency you are right it needs to be `api` if you use gradle for example, meaning the Interface bytecode needs to be in the classpath. For module system however looks like it's the transitive is not necessary, this is what I meant by asking if this can cause some confusion.

Comment: @GionJh It's not "necessary" if your application also declares an explicit dependency on the API module. But tracking all of the transitive dependencies can get unwieldy and error prone. So I would say it's "preferred" rather than "necessary"; there are kludges that can satisfy the readability requirement.

Comment: It also works without the explicit dependency looks like.